# Embed JavaScript in PDF with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, acrobat, wkhtmltopdf

Is it possible to [embed JavaScript code in PDFs](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acro6JSGuide.pdf) generated with wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: mid 2016: no it's not possible; or at least it is not documented - and I couldn't find out how this works. It seems like Adobe wants to let the `JavaScript for Acrobat API` die as well. better look for 3rd party printing software - if you wanted to use the embed JavaScript for printing/printer settings.

Answer (score 3):

In theory yes, the [change log for wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/699e8486fd42a2231c97f56bc1aed7117d8ab028/CHANGELOG-OLD) says that this is a feature in the most recent release. Of course the amount you will be able to do with it is limited - and the implementation linked to in that change log is different to the official Adobe documentation.

Comment: the link is dead. I am searching for this feature and now I don't know how it's called in wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @low_rents Somebody asked on GitHub, so response from the devs yet: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2003

Comment: @approxiblue but I still don't get it. Gareth says it is possible and there is a documentation. but I can't find a documenation link in the change log.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it is possible. The pdf converter only render follows your final html output...
Javascript always run when load or some interact with DOM. So it is not possible.